# PyDirectInput move endlessly to the upper left corner

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have tried using the PyDirectInput library to move the camera in games.
It didn't turn out to be a success. It seems to me that this happened due to the difference in the positioning of the cursor in the operating system (960, 540) and game (0, 0).
After shutting down PyCharm, I noticed slight cursor movement. After a while, the cursor began to move to the upper left corner, sometimes teleported to the bottom of the screen. This happens on all devices where I connected the mouse, even on Android OS
Again, PyCharm was closed at this point. I suspect that the mouse is trying to finish the commands, but it can't do it because I passed negative coordinates to moveTo(-961, -540) and move(-1, -1) to rotate the camera left and up. I passed a lot of random coordinates in the loop to understand the logic of the camera movement, so I would go crazy too :)
To clarify again, I connected another mouse and it works correctly, but the "crazy mouse" moves to the corner on other computers. Before using the library, everything was fine.

I tried to remove the drivers and reset the settings with the regular utility of the mouse manufacturer.